# plot 4 points on a raster grid in R

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have four points that represent the locations of four air quality monitoring stations. These four stations have the following parameters.

```
  Station              Lat  Long
1 Toronto Downtown      43.7 -79.4
2 Toronto East          43.7 -79.3
3 Toronto North         43.8 -79.5
4 Toronto West          43.7 -79.5
```

I want to create a raster that has the following parameters:

```
dimensions : 14, 26, 364  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.02, 0.02  (x, y)
extent     : -79.64, -79.12, 43.58, 43.86  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

I want to create a raster where the four stations are plotted in the cell that best represents their location. But the raster **has** to match the format I have provided. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what your question is, but I am guessing that you have trouble mapping this because your data is "lat/lon", rather than "lon/lat". You can solve that like this:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrow=24, ncol=26, xmin=-79.64, xmax=-79.12, ymin=43.58, ymax=43.86)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
d <- data.frame(Station=c("D", "E", "N", "W"), Lat=c(43.7,43.7,43.8,43.7), Lon=c(-79.4,-79.3,-79.5,-79.5))

plot(r)
points(d[, c("Lon", "Lat")])
```

Comment: I have air quality data for each of the four stations. I want to create a RasterStack where each layer is a day's worth of measurements (i.e. four measurements) across the stations. The reason I want it to be a raster, and not a point layer is because I want to compare the values with other raster files (wind speed, temperature). I want a clean, consistent grid across all of my variables, and I do not want to extract values from other rasters at the four points. Hope that clears things up and further guidance would be appreciated.